# Call Method from Another Class Not Working - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skscene

I have this in my "GameScene.m" class (SKScene):

```
GameViewController * game = [[GameViewController alloc] init];
[game imgMethod];
```

And I have this method in my "GameViewController.m" (UIViewController):

```
- (void)imgMethod{
    NSLog(@"test");
    img.alpha = 0.5;
}
```

And the thing is that the "test" is printed out, but the img.alpha = 0.5 doesn't work. I've made sure that the image is linked through the storyboard and that line works in the viewDidLoad method, but I need to call it from my GameScene class. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> "test" is printed out, but the img.alpha = 0.5 doesn't work

This will happen in two cases.

1. When you allocate a new memory for an existing object (`GameViewController` )
2. When you forgot to assign the `GameViewController`  `img` property from the `SKScene` class (after the `GameViewController` allocation).